# How do I accept a list of values from a form that is dynamically rendered in next js?

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot, next.js

What I'm trying to do is to render a certain part of my form which I've given as a list on my back-end

```html
{"trawlingNumber": trawlingNumber,
 "trawlingDate": trawlingDate,
 "totalVolume": totalVolume,
 "fishDetails": [
    {
      "fishType": fishType,
      "fishCategory": fishCategory,
      "fishGrade": fishGrade,
      "nofBoxes": nofBoxes,
      "position": position
     }
   ] 
}
```

```html
<form className={styles.formbox1} onSubmit={trawlingDetails}>
  <div className={styles.left}>
    <label className={styles.label1}>Trawling Number</label><br />
    <div className={styles.tnum}>
      <input className={styles.tbox} type="text" id="t1" name="tnum" defaultValue="13AD" value={trawlingNumber} onChange={e=> setTrawlingNumber(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.left}>
    <label className={styles.label2}>Trawling Date</label>
    <div className={styles.tdate}>
      <input className={styles.tbox} type="text" id="t2" name="tdate" defaultValue="17-03-2022" value={trawlingDate} onChange={e=> setTrawlingDate(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.left}>
    <label className={styles.label3}>Total Volume</label>
    <div className={styles.tvol}>
      <input className={styles.tbox} type="text" id="t3" name="tvol" defaultValue="1000" value={totalVolume} onChange={e=> setTotalVolume(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={styles.left}>
    <div className={styles.bar}>
      <label className={styles.label4}>type</label>
      <label className={styles.label5}>category</label>
      <label className={styles.label6}>Grade</label>
      <label className={styles.label7}>No of Boxes</label>
      <label className={styles.label8}>positions</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  {formValues.map((element, index) =>(
  <div className={styles.left} key={index}>
    <select className={styles.d1} defaultValue={element.fishType || ""} onChange={e=> handleChange(index, e)}>
      <option>Bluefin Tuna</option>
      <option>Angelfish</option>
      <option>Catfish</option>
    </select>
    <select className={styles.d2} defaultValue={element.fishCategory || ""} onChange={e=> handleChange(index, e)}>
      <option>BFT1</option>
      <option>BFT2</option>
      <option>BFT3</option>
      <option>AF1</option>
      <option>AF2</option>
      <option>AF3</option>
      <option>CF1</option>
      <option>CF2</option>
      <option>CF3</option>
    </select>
    <select className={styles.d3} defaultValue={element.fishGrade || ""} onChange={e=> handleChange(index, e)}>
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
    </select>
    <input className={styles.d4} type="text" defaultValue={element.nofBoxes || ""} onChange={e=> handleChange(index, e)} />
    <select className={styles.d5} defaultValue={element.position || ""} onChange={e=> handleChange(index, e)}>
      <option>S1F1Sl1</option>
      <option>S1F1Sl2</option>
      <option>S1F1Sl3</option>
      <option>S1F1Sl4</option>
      <option>S1F1Sl5</option>
      <option>S1F2Sl1</option>
      <option>S1F2Sl2</option>
      <option>S1F2Sl3</option>
      <option>S1F2Sl4</option>
      <option>S1F2Sl5</option>
      <option>S1F3Sl1</option>
      <option>S1F3Sl2</option>
      <option>S1F3Sl3</option>
      <option>S1F3Sl4</option>
      <option>S1F3Sl5</option>
      <option>S2F1Sl1</option>
      <option>S2F1Sl2</option>
      <option>S2F1Sl3</option>
      <option>S2F1Sl4</option>
      <option>S2F1Sl5</option>
      <option>S2F2Sl1</option>
      <option>S2F2Sl2</option>
      <option>S2F2Sl3</option>
      <option>S2F2Sl4</option>
      <option>S2F2Sl5</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ))}

  <div className={styles.left}>
    <div>
      <input className={styles.b1} type="button" id="b1" value="ADD" onClick={fdetails} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input className={styles.b1} type="submit" id="b1" value="SAVE" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

```js
let handleChange = (i, e) => {
  let newFormValues = [...formValues];
  newFormValues[i][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  setFormValues(newFormValues);
}

let fdetails = () => {
  setFormValues([...formValues, {
    fishType: "",
    fishCategory: "",
    fishGrade: "",
    nofBoxes: "",
    position: ""
  }])
}
```

**Expected Result**
So what I wanted my code would do was it would render this part of the form again when I click the add button so that it would accept the list of values.

**Actual Result** `
What happened was that It just reset all my inputs to blank and when I clicked save only the part of the form not in the formValue function only got inserted into the DB.

So was my logic in the right direction or was I completely off? I'm pretty much stuck here at this point. What should I do next?

Comment: Spring-boot? Where does this fit on the picture?

Comment: well all my apis are done on it.